# adding getTotal to website

Tags: php

I need to add a total to the categories of an online classifieds website. These totals will dynamically change just as the categories can so it needs to update each time the page loads. I believe i need to use a getTotal command but don't know how or where to input it. Thanks in advance for any help.

The code currently looks like this:

```
<div class="submenu">
        <?php
        foreach($catList as $row){
        ?>
        <div class="submenutxt"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>category/listing/<?php echo $row->meta_title;?>"><?php echo $row->category_name;?> </a></div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: sorry....total amount of products within each category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total number of rows in `$catList`:

```
<?php

    echo "$total rows: <br />";
    foreach($catList as $row) { ?>
        echo (count($row))." items in this category";  
...
```

Comment: Sorry, i may not have been clear enough. Within each category is a number of products, i want the code to count the total of each category and put the number in brackets beside that category name. For example: toys (16), boats (22) etc